# Release notes component for internal development to internal users

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, lightning-experience, developer

I have been searching for a solution already made for displaying a release notes popup or notification to our internal users after we deploy changes to my Salesforce production org.

All my searching land me on Salesforce release notes but I want release notes for our development, is there any app that provide that feature or should I just build something custom?

Comment: Do you have any specifics in mind with regards to what a "release notes component" would look like? Would an [in-app guidance prompt](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000349069&type=1&mode=1) that links to your release notes suffice?

Comment: Hi @KrisGoncalves looks promising, I will take a look at the documentation more in depths and see If it can achieve what I had in mind. Thank you!

Comment: @KrisGoncalves This will work for  my purpose, if you want to add your comment as answer I could select it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an out-of-the-box approach that can be rolled out quickly, I'd look into [in-app guidance prompts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000349069&type=1&mode=1) (`Setup --> In-App Guidance`)

> Add in-app guidance to your org using clicks, not code. To engage
> directly with your users, write your own content and include action
> buttons to your chosen URL in the prompts. You can specify the target
> audience and where the prompts appear and for how long.

At the very least, you could alert the user you had a release and provide an action button to your long release notes stored on whatever platform you'd like. Other configurations you can take advantage of:

- Only show the prompt to specific profiles (Admins, etc)
- Provide a button that opens a URL
- Specify the scheduled (start date, end date, times to show)

Likewise, if you have a big or new feature - you could make a prompt that specifically brings it to users' attentions on the given page.

There's even [walkthroughs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpTlNMLSc3o) now (you can have 3 active ones for free) that can provide linked prompts.

Comment: Thanks again, I have setup docked prompt which aren't limited like walkthroughts and I can have release notes displayed during a period of time to targeted users so far I believe it will be exactly what I was looking for. The only limitation that might be a problem is the body maximum characters limit but I can always make a 2nd prompt if needed